# Unused Variable in g++ compiler

Tags: c++, gcc-warning

```
void num_chars(vector<string> words)
{
    ifstream fin("textfile.txt");
    if (fin.fail())
    {
        error("Could not open file for fin");
    }

    char z = fin.get();
    int char_count = 0;
    while (!fin.eof())
    {
        ++char_count;
        z = fin.get();
    }
    cout << words[1] << " contains " << char_count << " characters. \n\n";
}
```

I'm not sure why char z is an unused variable.  I thought I need to initialize it before the while loop so I can start with the first character in the text file and  continuously get the next characters. Also sorry if the formatting for code blocks is wrong, not sure how to do it properly.

Comment: From the code you posted, the value stored in `z` is never used for anything.

Comment: You also have undefined behavior that will occur if the `words` vector has less than two items.

Comment: It is perfectly valid to just do `fin.get()` without assigning the result to anything if you just want to get a character and throw it away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have only assigned the value to the variable z, be it before the loop or in the loop, but you have not used the value (say printing it, or using it for any manipulation), hence the warning is shown that the variable is unused.

Unused does not mean that it is not used in program or it has not been assigned any value, unused means that the variable is useless right now.